# CSS3 Animations: Can I leave out the "to" values?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

My code currently looks like this:

```
@keyframes lfade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: 45px;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0px; //this line
  }
}
```

Can I remove the `margin-left` line in the `to` block so the browser uses the default margin for the object I'm trying to animate instead of `0px`?
It seems to work in Firefox and Opera, but I wasn't able to find any official sources.

Comment: i can confirm it in chrome and ie11 as well.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you can but first you have to specify the original margin left in the stylsheet of what you are animating before taking it out like this :

```
    #tag { width: 200; margin-left:45;}//you just do what you know overthere
```

then set your animation tags

```
       @keyframes lfade {
                           from {
                       opacity: 0;
                        margin-left: 45px;
                            }

                      to {
                      opacity: 1;
                      margin-left: 0px; //this line
                   }
                  }
```

try this

Comment: this way it will not animate the margin at all.

Comment: maybe depending on the type of browsers